# Provide power via GPIO

Tags: gpio

I have a RPi2 with a touchscreen attached.  All the supply pins are covered by the screen jumper.   I'd like to set up a small thermistor circuit.  My question is - can I use a standard GPIO pin set to high to provide 3.3v or would the current draw be too high?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Hopefully it's clear in what sense this is a duplicate.  The (recommended) max output per pin (and in total) is documented there as well as various other places.  Whether that is enough for what you want depends on the requirements of the thermistor circuit.

Comment: Thanks Goldilocks for helping. It was just the sort of direction I was looking for.   If I could trouble you a bit further do you think it would be ok for https://learn.adafruit.com/thermistor/using-a-thermistor.   I suspect yes but an second opinion would be great.

Comment: I'm no electronics guru (and general electronics questions should go to our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)), but I think applying a little [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) should settle this; the current requirement in *amps* would be `3.3 / max circuit resistance`.

Comment: Sounds like me teaching!  Thanks.  As long as it's that simple and I'm not missing anything I should be ok.